# Dependency Injection, constructor with custom and simple object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I've a class as follows -

```
public class GCCUPCCodeGenerator : IUPCCodeGenerator
{
    IPersistence _persistence;
    string _gccPrefix;

    public GCCUPCCodeGenerator(IPersistence persistence , string gccPrefix)
    {
        _persistence = persistence;
    }
```

How do I accomplish dependency injection for this object in Startup.cs?

Here is what I know  -

**A.** If this class just needed the IPersistence class, I would have added-

```
   services.AddScoped<IPersistence, Persistence>();
```

**B.** And finally if this were a class with simple types in the constructor, I know how to read values from a Config to create the object.

For the UnixConnection class -

```
public class UnixConnection : IUnixDataStore
{
    public UnixConnection(UnixConnectionOption connectionOptions)
    {
```

Startup.cs -

```
services.AddScoped<IUnixDataStore>(provider => ConfigureUnixConnectionObject());
IUnixDataStore ConfigureUnixConnectionObject()
    {
        var connectionParam = new UnixConnectionOption
        {
            DBPort = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["DBPort"]),
            SSHUserName = Configuration["SSHUserName"],
            SSHHostName = Configuration["SSHHostName"],
            SSHPassword = Configuration["SSHPassword"],
            SQLHostName = Configuration["SQLHostName"],
            SQLUserName = Configuration["SQLUserName"],
            SQLPassword = Configuration["SQLPassword"],
            SQLDatabaseName = Configuration["SQLDatabaseName"]
        };
        return new UnixConnection(connectionParam);
    }
```

Comment: are you getting an error? your configutartion looks logical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the provider action overload, much the same as in your second scenario (which ironically does *not* need this to get it done).

```
services.AddScoped<IUPCCodeGenerator>(p =>
{
    // `p` is a scoped instance of `IServiceProvider`, meaning you can pull services from it
    var persistence = p.GetRequiredService<IPersistence>();
    return new GCCUPCCodeGenerator(persistence, "prefix");
});
```

The prefix of course can come from your config.

Not related to your question, but since I mentioned that you didn't need to do this for your `IUnixDataStore`. If your config used sections (which it should, since having a bunch of unrelated config settings all at the root can lead to confusion and errors) then you can bind the section for `UnixConnectionOptions` via strongly-typed config. Assuming config like:

```
{
    "UnixConnection": {
      "DBPort": "...",
      "SSHUserName": "...",
      ...
    }
}
```

(Note: if using something like environment variables, you can "section" using `:`, i.e. `UnixConnection:DBPort`)

Then:

```
services.Configure<UnixConnectionOption>(Configuration.GetSection("UnixConnection"));
```

After that, you have a few choices. If you don't mind injecting `IOptions<UnixConnectionOption>` or `IOptionsSnapshot<UnixConnectionOption>` instead, then you're done. That actually has benefit as you can take advantage of things like config reload.

If you really want to stick to injecting `UnixConnectionOptions` directly, then you simply need to add another line like:

```
services.AddScoped<UnixConnectionOptions>(p =>
    p.GetRequiredService<IOptions<UnixConnectionOptions>>().Value);

services.AddScoped<IUnixDataStore, UnixConnection>();
```

Since the required dependency is directly in the service collection, it can inject directly without you needing to provide a custom action. Or, you can stick to how you're doing it currently, but at least take advantage of reduced code:

```
services.AddScoped<IUnixDataStore>(p => {
    var connectionParam = p.GetRequiredService<IOptions<UnixConnectionOption>>();
    return new UnixConnection(connectionParam.Value);
);
```

Comment: I would be adding - services.AddScoped<IPersistence, Persistence>(); anyways in the Startup since another class needs IPersistence, so adding another IPersistence to the services collection when creating the IUPCCodeGenerator service should not be an issue - right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The line there is pulling the instance out, not registering it again. If this needs an entirely different implementation of IPersistence, then you'll need a different strategy for that in general, because you cannot register multiple implementations for the same interface.

Comment: You'd need to use generics or a factory in such a case.

Comment: Sorry, I was not reading it right.
it looks like it should work and it makes sense, I'll update if I run into an issue.
On the config section, this code is old and back then I did not know of it, but yes, I use it now and the reduced code is a great benefit.